# Issue on Drawing Multiple Circles on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Can you please take a [look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/56jhq/1/) demo and let me know how I can draw multiple circles in a canvas with different coordinate  without repeating bunch of codes?

As you can see on Demo and following code

```
var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#00A308";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 50, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.arc(20, 85, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.arc(160, 95, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

I tried to have them under `ctx` but it is not correct so I tried to use for loop to create 50 points but I have issue on repeating and adding code like ctx.fill(); for all of them.
Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are not closing the path, either using `fill()` or `closePath()` will close the path so it does not try and connect all the items. `fill()` fills in the circles and closes the path so we can just use that. Also you need to use `beginPath()`, so that they are separate from each other. Here is your three circles:

```
var coords = [ [150,50], [20,85], [160,95] ];

for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

To not repeat a bunch of code and have unique coordinates store your `X` and `Y` position in an array and use a `for` loop to go through it.

**Update:**

A more efficient way to do which achieves the same effect this would be to only use a single path and use [`moveTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/moveTo) instead of creating a new path when drawing each circle:

```
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
    ctx.moveTo(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
    ctx.arc(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
}
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer, can you also please let me know how I can set stroke for dots?

Comment: Do you mean like using `ctx.stroke()` other than `ctx.fill()`?

Comment: Not sure but your code not working now! did you have a chance to test it?

Comment: I did, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56jhq/2/ . I didn't include things such as getting the `ctx` in the example code.

Comment: Adria's Answer below is better, more Paths = wasted time.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, can we also add click event in each shape created?

Comment: @Gajen No but you can add it to the canvas it self and check to see if the mouse position intersects a circle. For example [here is a modification of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56jhq/49/) that uses Circle Objects and the distance formula for checking intersections. (*Note it shows in the console log*)

Answer (score 18):

Constantly creating and closing new paths is not good advice.

You should batch together all fills / strokes of the same style, and execute them in a single draw call. The performance difference between these approaches becomes apparent very quickly with increasing polygon count.

The way to go about it is to move the pen and make the path construction call for each circle; stroke/fill in the end in one shot.  However, there's a quirk involved here.  When you have the point moved to the center and draw the circle, *you'd still see a horizontal radius line*, drawn from the center of the circle, to the circumference.

To avoid this artefact, instead of moving to the center, we move to the circumference.  This skips the radius drawing.  Essentially all these commands are for tracing a path and there's no way to describe a discontinuity without calling `closePath`; usually `moveTo` does it but HTML5 canvas API it doesn't.  This is a simple workaround to counter that.

```
const pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
const radius = 5;
ctx.fillStyle = '#00a308';
ctx.beginPath();

for( let i=0, l=coords.length; i < l; i++ )
{
    const p = coords[i],
    x = p.x,
    y = p.y;

    ctx.moveTo( x + radius, y ); // This was the line you were looking for
    ctx.arc( x, y, radius, 0, pi2 );
}

// Finally, draw outside loop
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

Also worth considering, is using transformations, and drawing everything relative to a local frame of reference.

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#00a308';
ctx.beginPath();

for( let i=0, l=coords.length; i < l; i++ )
{
    const p = coords[i];

    ctx.save();
        ctx.translate( p.x + radius, p.y );
        ctx.moveTo( 0, 0 );
        ctx.arc( 0, 0, radius, 0, pi2 );
    ctx.restore();
}

ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: This is great advice. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/Lmuyqb27/3/

Comment: This is a much better answer as it allows drawing in batches. I was confused because there seems to be an implicit `moveTo` performed under the hood in `rect` (or some other mechanism that makes an explicit call unnecessary), where as without this explicit `moveTo`, all `arc` calls are joined together when drawn.

Comment: @thedarklord47 I went ahead and added a more performant version to the accepted answer. While this is indeed a better approach I'd like to note that my answer was mainly based on the issue the OP had and what they wanted to do: *"I have issue on repeating and adding code like ctx.fill(); for all of them. Can you please let me know how I can fix this?"*.

Comment: @Adria any sense of which is more performant, approach #1 or #2 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  ctx.beginPath();
  points.forEach(point => {
    ctx.moveTo( point.x, point.y );
    ctx.arc(point.x,point.y,1,0,Math.PI*2,false);
  });
  ctx.fill();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This has better performance than the accepted answer. It calls `fil()` only once

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create several circles with a for loop. You really just need to draw an arc and fill it each time. Using your example, you could do something like this.

```
var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#00A308";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ctx.arc(50 * (i+1), 50 + 15 * i, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Hi Zack , thanks for reply but can also let me know how I can set border for each circle? and is there any way to use custom cordinates for each of the circles? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/l1ght/FMe3W/) of lots of circles in different locations drawn in a loop.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var cx = canvas.width/2;
var cy = canvas.height/2;
ctx.fillStyle = "#00A308";

var total_circles = 50;
var radius = 100;
for(i = 0; i < total_circles; i++){
    var angle = i * 2 * Math.PI/total_circles;
    var x = cx + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
    var y = cy + Math.sin(angle) * radius;   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```