# canvas path connects when I'm closing them using the new path ()

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm creating paths with `new Path2D ()` and setting them on objects to later check with `isPathInPoint()`.

I'm trying to create 4 circles around a box, but the circles are being connected with each draw. I know I can just create a new path each time and then push them into an array, but I wonder if it's possible to just use one path and create them without connecting?

Here is a simple example:

```
            this.hoverPath = new Path2D();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = solidColor;
            this.hoverPath.arc(this.x + this.width, this.y + (this.height / 2), size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = solidColor;
            this.hoverPath.arc(this.x + (this.width /2), this.y + this.height, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

            ctx.fill(this.hoverPath);
```

This will create two circles, but there will be a line connected them.

If I create the other two it will make a box inbetween them connected. How can I achieve this without pushing them into an array and then creating a new path, or is this just how it has to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to move before you add the circles...

See my sample below, first four have no move and we get the same issue you describe:
[image]

On the second I'm using the move and it looks good:
[image]

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
var size = 15

var pos = {x: 45, y: 45}
var hoverPath = new Path2D();
hoverPath.arc(pos.x - 25, pos.y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x, pos.y - 25, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x + 25, pos.y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x, pos.y + 25, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill(hoverPath);
ctx.stroke(hoverPath);

pos = {x: 160, y: 45}
hoverPath = new Path2D();
hoverPath.moveTo(pos.x - 25 + size, pos.y);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x - 25, pos.y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
hoverPath.moveTo(pos.x + size, pos.y - 25);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x, pos.y - 25, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
hoverPath.moveTo(pos.x + 25 + size, pos.y);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x + 25, pos.y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
hoverPath.moveTo(pos.x + size, pos.y + 25);
hoverPath.arc(pos.x, pos.y + 25, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill(hoverPath);
ctx.stroke(hoverPath);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Don't moveTo the center, you are tracing a line the size of the radius for nothing. Instead directly moveTo the entry point in the arc as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737509/3702797

Comment: @Kaiido good advise and simple just a `+ radius`