# What causes drawing clipping in an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, radial-gradients

I've got an HTML5 canvas, on which I'm drawing a series of radial gradients:

```
const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, radius / 10, x, y, radius);

gradient.addColorStop(0, colour);
gradient.addColorStop(1, "transparent");

ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
```

But the more of these that get rendered, they start to clip, as you can see in the screenshot below.  This is the only thing being rendered on this canvas, and I'm not performing any other canvas context actions.  Is this a performance issue or something else?

[image: radial gradient image clipping]

Note: this is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668459/issue-on-drawing-multiple-circles-on-html5-canvas), as my question is not regarding repeating code, but instead regarding clipping occurring if you don't begin a new path while drawing

Comment: You forgot a `beginPath()` call, all your arcs compose a single big subpath and where it crosses itself you get weird fill rules.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer from Kaiido

> You forgot a beginPath() call, all your arcs compose a single big subpath and where it crosses itself you get weird fill rules.